# Porting Android to nanoTesla A8

Tags: android, build, porting, cortex-a8, android-embedded-api

We have an embedded device in our organisation that has a nanoTesla A8 board and runs linux.

We want to run android on the device to develop android apps for our device.

Is it possible to run Android on nanoTesla? Is there any porting available for Android on nanoTesla?

Or Do I have to cross compile android?

Any inputs will be helpful.a

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Android Embedded](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do)